# Pagination in Google charts?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am using Google charts to show some graphs in my website. The thing is I have too many periods (by weeks), imagine two years, I would have over 100 weeks, the chart really becomes incomprehensible, so I thought about adding some kind of pagination by month, is this possible?

```
$j('#Summary').Chart({
    chartClass: google.visualization.AreaChart,
    chartOptions: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        width: '100%',
        height: 400,
        hAxis: { title: 'time' },
        vAxis: { title: 'contents' },
        isStacked: true
    },
    chartData: data,
    setCertainty: true
});
```

Comment: how does your data look like?

Comment: How about using a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) to pan and zoom your data?

Comment: as @asgallant mentioned, how about ChartRangerFilter? I think it would do what you're looking for great, check out the example here: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#chartrangefilter_control *adjust the sides of the white box below the graph

Comment: You can also use the [explorer option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) to enable clicking and dragging on the chart to pan, and zooming via the mousewheel.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you this is what you are looking for

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples#tablequerywrapper

Is a table, but is paginated

If not, try to implement some system to move ranges between your data. Some example, will help